# Comparing multiple columns for match

Tags: match

Can someone please assist me with the following.

I have a data base of member names. names in column C (Main). I then want to compare this column to another database column c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l on another sheet (booked via google form) for a match, resulting in a tickbox to be marked if the name on the main sheet is listed on the (booked via google form) sheet.

Currently im using this formula to compare and tick the box, but its limited to only comparing it to one column and not multiple columns.

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C3,'Booked via google form'!C:C,0)),False,TRUE)

is there a better way to do this or can this be adjusted to look for a match in multiple columns?

Comment: Also is there a way to have the tickbox to still be manually ticked? or is the only way to remove the fromula?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so did some searching and found the following formula that works.

=IF(COUNTIF('Booked via google form'!C:L, "*"&C3&"*")=0, FALSE, TRUE)

This allows me to search through all the names on the booked via form sheet.

any additional input is still welcome.